# Is there a tag or remark feature in arm assembly for debugging?

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly

It's a bit of a silly questions...

Is there a tag or remark system in arm-gcc compiler? To figure out how to arm compiler interpret instructions.

For example if i mark something in the code such as...

```
uint8x8_t result = vadd_u8(op0,op1); # some tag USER_DEF
```

After compiler optimize and build assembly code, compiler mark some tag in the assembly code like below.

```
add x1, x2, x3 // USER_DEF
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  What are you trying to achieve?  Try compiling with debug information.

Comment: "To figure out how arm compiler interpret instructions", if that's all you want to achieve, try (https://godbolt.org/). It shows how the lines are translated to assembly by color.

Comment: For casual usage, you can just use inline assembly: `asm("// magic begins here");`.  It can have some effect on optimization, though.

Comment: I did tagging using `nop`-s to check what compiler doing with piece of code in some particular section. `asm volatile ("nop\tnop\tnop\tnop\t")` one at the beginning and one at the end. After that just searched dump for that instruction groups

Comment: @user3124812: asm comments are less intrusive, or if you're using Godbolt's filtering, `asm("nop // Hi mom, look at me!");` will make the line a non-comment.  If you're not going to run it or even assemble it, it doesn't matter what text you put on the line.  Multiple `nop`s on one line won't assemble anyway, so it's a weird choice.  If you want something that won't appear anywhere else in the compiler's asm output, `asm("xyz")` is a likely unique string.  Something the assembler will choke on is probably actually a good thing, so you don't accidentally leave it in for release builds. (@Nate)